# What is the express.js equivalent of the node.js http module's "req.url"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When using vanilla node.js' http.createServer, you can get the url that the client requested with req.url.

When using express.js, the code for responding to a HTTP GET request is something like:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})
```

My problem with this is that it requires you to have an individual app.get for every single page or item on the server. How do I use express.js like the vanilla node.js server to deal with each get request within the callback generated by the http.createServer?

Comment: Static pages (that do not have custom content or custom code behind them) can all be served by common static routes.  See http://expressjs.com/api.html#express.static for details.  Pages that each require individual customization must have code that matches each page.  Routes can also be generic so the same handler function serves everything in a particular directory hierarchy.  You really ought to spend more time with the Express documentation and doing reading on the web.  There are lots of capabilities and lots written about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't ever have a need to use `req.url`.  Express allows you to have variables in your routes.

```
app.get('/article/:id', function(req, res) {
    // req.params.id will be whatever came after /article/
});
```

You can also get fancy and use a regular expression.

```
app.get(/\/article(\d+)/, function(req, res) {
    // req.params[0] will have the digits of /article123
});
```

If you *really* want the URL, `req.url` still exists.  However, you should use routes to handle all your routing logic.  I've never really had the need to use `req.url`.

Answer (score 2):

Hi

To answer the specific question ***(as outlined in your title)***, ExpressJS provides

- [req.originalURL](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.originalUrl) which is equivalent to Node's **req.url**
- [req.baseUrl](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.baseUrl) which is actually the path that was mounted by Express

So, essentially, Express' ***req.baseUrl*** + ***req.url*** is equivalent to Node's ***req.url***

Also, Express' routing ***DOES NOT*** require you to explicitly set the path to each page; it also accepts regex strings with which you can process specific requests.

Take a look at [Express' routing](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router); it should be of immense benefit to you.

Comment: It's not mentioned in the docs, but `req.url` exists.  As the Express request object is a subclass of node's http `ClientRequest` object, all of the properties from node's http are available on an Express `req`.

Comment: Express's **req.url** WILL NOT give you the same values as Node's **req.url** *(unless the mounted path is "/")* ; it'll give you the URL relative to the mounted path; its **req.originalUrl** is the equivalent.

Comment: Misread your post.  To be clear, `req.baseUrl + req.url == req.originalUrl == ClientRequest#url`.  (Unless you have middleware that rewrites the URL.)  Still, if you're doing mounting, `req.url`'s behavior may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Register you followup handler like an express module...

`app.use(function(req, res, next){ ... YOUR CODE HERE ... })`

Do this after your routes...